# How to prevent https://www.mozilla.org/en/privacy/firefox/ from opening?

Tags: batch-file, firefox

I created a script that allows to create a temporary profile then launches the firefox browser.

Everything works correctly except for one small detail, each time the https://www.mozilla.org/fr/privacy/firefox/ page opens in a second tab

```
start C:\"Program Files"\"Mozilla Firefox"\firefox.exe -profile %TEMP_PROFILE% %URL%
```

My script works fine, firefox launches my temporary profile fine. But open the https://www.mozilla.org/fr/privacy/firefox/ tab each time

How can I prevent it from opening?

[image]

Comment: `C:\"Program Files"\"Mozilla Firefox"\firefox.exe` is an invalid file name. The Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) explains that the character `"` is not allowed within a file/folder name. The help output on running `cmd /?` explains that a file (or folder name or any other argument string) containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` (or `<>|` as in a password) must be enclosed in `"` to get these characters interpreted literally by `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Why does `C:\"Program Files"\"Mozilla Firefox"\firefox.exe` work? The automatic error corrections applied by the Windows file IO functions and by `cmd.exe` after several negative returns from the file system changes that invalid file name into the valid file name `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` and then `cmd.exe` calls the the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) for running `firefox.exe` as a process executed parallel to `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

Comment: Open a command prompt window, enter `C:\Pro` and press key __TAB__ for a file/folder name completion. You see the string modified to `"C:\Program Files"`. Press again key __TAB__ and `cmd` changes the string to `"C:\Program Files (x86)"` as that is the next file/folder matched by `C:\Pro*` in file system. Press once more key __TAB__ and the string changes to `C:\ProgramData`. There are no `"` anymore as not needed for this folder path. Press key __TAB__ to get back to `"C:\Program Files"` and continue typing with `\Moz` and press key __TAB__. Displayed is: `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"`

Comment: You see that the second `"` is moved to the end. Now you have learned how to use the file/folder name completion on entering a file/folder name in a command prompt window and how to specify file/folder names correct in a command prompt window or a batch file (or any other script file which passes the string to an executable). Run now `start /?` and read the output usage help. The first string enclosed in `"` after the command __START__ is interpreted as optional title for the console window. That is important to know as `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"` is enclosed in `"`.

Comment: It is therefore necessary to explicitly specify the optional window title. That can be done in this case with `""` which is an empty title string because of *Firefox* is a Windows GUI application. `CreateProcess` does not create a console window for that reason at all. The console window title string can be therefore also an empty title string. The 100% correct command line not causing several file system accesses and automatic error corrections would be `start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -profile "%TEMP_PROFILE%" "%URL%"` without knowing `TEMP_PROFILE` and `URL`.

Comment: There is the Mozilla Wiki page [Firefox / Command Line Options](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions) and the Mozilla Developer Network page [Command Line Options - Mozilla](http://www.devdoc.net/web/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options.html). If you cannot find an option which results in creating a new profile and opening only a tab with the additionally specified URL, you have to run *Firefox* without command `start` first to just create the profile without starting fully. Then modify the profile settings if necessary to avoid opening the privacy page.

Comment: And last `start` *Firefox* with that profile and with the URL to open the page you want to get opened by Firefox using the already created and prepared new profile with the URL. There is not described why there is not simply used `start "" "%URL%"` to start the web browser preferred by the user for showing the page according to the specified URL. The entire approach smells like using *Firefox* for something malicious.

Comment: This is not malicious activity, but I have issues in a professional environment. The use of firefox is mandatory and profiles must be purged and created on the fly

Comment: I don't want to use another browser by default, you are right about the syntax of launching firefox so I fix this. I want to specify new profile in the command line and the URL to open automaticaly my web page which is forced for my all users

Comment: I know it is not a standard use because it is for a very particular use

Comment: I found a technique I make a profile by default and I copy this profile with all preference for all users

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "TemporaryProfile" -new-tab "https://www.google.com/"
exit
```

Make sure to replace `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` with the actual path to your Firefox executable.

This batch script will launch Firefox with the "TemporaryProfile" profile and open a new tab with with https://www.google.com.

Comment: I think you did not understand my problem, I already managed to launch firefox with a temporary profile

Comment: I'm not facing the same issue as you.

Maybe there is some problem with your firefox. How you tried to reinstall it? There might be some problem within your firefox settings.

If you don't want to reinstall firefox try modifying your script for microsoft edge or google chrome to check if you get the same issue with them or not.

Comment: I have the impression that this is the default page that opens when it comes to a new profile. I edit my post

Comment: It should not, cuz I'm not having this issue, neither with Google Chrome nor with FireFox. Maybe consider switching to Chrome instead.

Comment: Do you test with different profiles ?

Comment: No, I didn't, but I strongly feel this is a browser related issue. You should consider trying this on chrome or edge. I got no issues on any browser.

Comment: You can also use python for that. It might resolve the issue.